# String with does not contain clause in c# visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

VB c# beginner here. I am using the following snippet of code to list out all the videos in a directory.

```
    var files = Directory
        .GetFiles("D:\\Movies", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".mp4") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".mkv") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".avi"));
```

Now the challenge is to exclude those videos which have 'sample' word in their names.

I tried adding `.Where(s => s != "sample.avi");` at the end but it doesn't seem to work.

also when I do `.Where(s => s.Contains("sample");`, I am able to list out all the files which have the word 'sample' in their names.

Also is it possible to delete those names from the `files` array or enum whatever that is ? I don't think that works as an array because finding the count doesn't work like `files.Count` / `files.Length`.

I think my understanding of enums and string is a little weak here. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to the method `.GetFiles()` is the search pattern you need not to perform anymore filtering if you specifying the search pattern here: you will get all files with name sample if you give the pattern as: `"sample.*"`  or you will get all files whose name ends with sample but having any extension by using `"*Sample.*"` So use like this:

```
 string pattern="sample.avi";
 var files = Directory
        .GetFiles("D:\\Movies", pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If you want to use multiple filters means use like this:

```
string pattern="sample.*";
var files = Directory
            .GetFiles("D:\\Movies", pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".mp4") || 
            s.EndsWith(".mkv",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)||
            s.EndsWith(".avi",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

So the `.GetFiles()` will give you all the files having name as sample the Where will filter files with extension .mkv or .avi or mp4

Comment: this will only fetch me files with names sample.avi, What I want to achieve is all the files which do not contain the word 'sample' in their names.

Comment: Using `ToLower` will create a bunch of unnecessary strings.  Use the overload of `EndsWith` that allow you to specify a case insensitive search:  `s.EndsWith(".mkv", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: thanks for the advise, it helps me to improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for String.IndexOf(string)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Returns -1 if not found. If any other value is returned, name contains the argument string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, got it to work by using

`.Where(s => !s.ToLower().Contains("sample"));`

This excludes the names which have 'sample' word in them.

Comment: Don't use `ToLower`.  You are just creating a bunch of unnecessary strings.  Use the overload of `Contains` that allow you to specify a case insensitive search:  `.Where(s => !s.Contains("sample", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));`